# Are there definitions of the quotient of two whole numbers that does not use Euclidean Division?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition, education

Be forewarned - the following is a pedagogical presentation of really simple stuff and you might not be interested.

Since I posed the question, let me provide one such definition.

Assume both $m$ and $b$ are in $\mathbb{N}$ with $b > 0$.

We can assert the following for $\mathbb{N}$:

Archimedean Property: The set $\mathcal {Q_b}^m\;$ :$\,\{q^`$ with $m \ge q^`b\}$ is a finite interval $[0,\; q]$.

Definition: The set $\mathcal {Q_b}^m$ is called "division of $m$ by $b$".

Definition: The largest number $q$ in $\mathcal {Q_b}^m$ is called "the quotient of division of $m$ by $b$".

Proposition 2: $r = m - qb$ is in $\mathbb{N}$ and must also be less than $b$.

Proof: Totally obvious.

Definition: The number $r$ is called "the remainder of division of $m$ by $b$".

Theorem: If $m = q^{'}b + r^{'}$ with  $r^{'} < b$, then $q^{'}=q$ and $r^{'}=r$.

Proof: It easy to show that $q^{'}$ is the maximum number in $\mathcal {Q_b}^m$ since $q^{'} + 1$ does not work.

QED

For completeness:

$m$ is called the dividend and $b$ is called the divisor.

Comment: And how is this any different from Euclidean Division?

Comment: You should read about the system of Peano postulates (axioms) for $\mathbb N$, called Peano Arithmetic (PA). The fact that there exists $q' $with $q'm>b$ is called the Archimedean property.

Comment: Yes @danielwainfleet - I can improve the presentation. Thanks!

Comment: @Kenny et.al. - just thought this might be fun. Sorry if you did not find the question's wording humorous (it was tongue in cheek). Also, sometimes in more complicated situations one should look for alternative viewpoints.

Comment: If someone has seen this proof before please let me know. I found a similar proof - see http://www.math.fsu.edu/~pkirby/mad2104/SlideShow/s5_1.pdf where the remainder 'pops out' first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a variation of the Euclidean algorithm which is "subtractive". In some interpretations, it is what the original algorithm of Euclid was intended to be. The key point is what does it mean for one number to "measure" another? It could mean to repeatedly subtract the smaller number from the larger number. This seems essentially equivalent to your definition. They both do not use division. In Euclid the algorithm was used for "quantities" first and there is no definition of "division" for these. Thus, it indicates that division was not intended for numbers as well.

Comment: getting plenty of hits with "subtractive Euclidean algorithm"